# Figure with clusters of different color in python

Tags: python, plot, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe that has 6 columns. The most important would be "Longitude", "latitude" and "id_cluster".

I want each point X, Y to be plotted for each id_clusters. In total there are 7 clusters that must be of different colors in the graph

I have this code:

```
train = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Jonat\Downloads\denstream-master\denstream-master\output\beijing.xlsx")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
plt.plot(train['longitud'], train['latitud'], ".b", markersize=15)
```

This is my dataframe:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXS0q.png)

I want something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcSf5.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of your datasets, try to add them as code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Seaborn package to easily create a scatterplot of your clusters and color points according to cluster.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.scatterplot(data=train, x="longitude", y="latitude", hue="id_cluster")
```

Comment: Thank you. on the other hand, do you know of any library that helps me to graph maps likewise with grouped trajectories?

Comment: @ServicesPuzzlesConsulting you'll probably need to create a new question for that